# What are the advantages/disadvantages to trading a stock listed on multiple exchanges on a US-based exchange vs foreign exchange?

Tags: stocks, investing, trading, international-trading

I'm a relatively new trader. My goal is trading with a longer-term horizon in mind. That is, I plan to rebalance on an annual/bi-annual basis, and purchase whenever I see reasonable/fair valuations. My country does not have capital gain taxes for assets held > 1 year, and trading commissions aren't too bad. I'm not in the US.

Let's say I see a stock I like. For example, consider Toyota, the car manufacturer/automaker. It is a Japanese company that is listed on the Tokyo stock exchange (TSEJ) and the New York Stock Exchange (NYSE).

Is it better to purchase the asset on the non-US exchange, or the US-based one? What are the advantages/disadvantages of one over the other?
The only things I considered so far are forex conversions, trading commissions and impending delisting (e.g. Chinese stocks). What am I missing?

Comment: In most cases, you cannot buy foreign stocks on American exchanges. what is listed on American exchanges are ADRs (American Depositary Receipts), which represent some number of the stock held by some custodian in the US (BNY Mellon mostly). So you don't really "own" anything, and you can easily lose access to them as happened with some of the Russian ADRs.